# Calculations on product price without tax

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I'm using this WooCommerce function **`woocommerce_price($product->get_price_excluding_tax());`** 
to display the price without TAX.

But I want to make some **calculations before** with this price, for example, **to divide it**...

With `echo woocommerce_price($product->get_price_excluding_tax());`
it displays the price with currency, for example **`€13.80`**. So I remove the € symbol from the string with this code:

```
$taxed_price = woocommerce_price($product->get_price_excluding_tax());
$taxed_price = str_replace("&euro;","",$taxed_price);
echo $taxed_price = str_replace('"', "", $taxed_price);
echo $excl_tax_price = $taxed_price/2;
```

But my calculation on **`$taxed_price/2`** doesn't work, it don't get divided.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> First [**`woocommerce_price()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_price.html#314-319) is a **deprecated**, instead you should use [**`wc_price()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_price.html#400-433) function.

**This function allow to format the price with a currency symbol.**

> You just have to use it after your calculations, to avoid using **`str_replace()`** php function to remove that formatted currency symbol and get the correct calculations, this way:

```
// Making your calculation (dividing)
$excl_tax_price = $product->get_price_excluding_tax()/2;

// Displaying this calculation (non formatted, no currency symbol):
echo $excl_tax_price;

// Displaying this formatted calculation (with currency symbol):
echo wc_price($excl_tax_price);
```